# Как правильно создать маппер генератором словаря?

Tags: python, ооп

У меня есть набор классов с необходимыми методами. Примеры классов ниже.

```
class FirstClass:
    
    def check_method_1(self):
        return 'check_1'
     
    
    def check_method_2(self):
        return 'check_2'


class SecondClass:
    
    def check_method_3(self):
        return 'check_3'

   
    def check_method_4(self):
        return 'check_4'


class ThirdClass:


    def check_method_5(self):
        return 'check_5'


    def check_method_6(self):
        return 'check_6'
```

На их основании хочу сделать маппинг имен методов и самих функций:

```
mapper = {'check_method_1': FirstClass.check_method_1, 'check_method_4': SecondClass.check_method_4, ...}
```

Я могу это все вручную сделать, но хочу генератором словаря с этим справиться. Что-то типа такого:

```
classes = FirstClass, SecondClass, ThirdClass
mapper = {str(method_name):cls.method_name for cls in classes}
```

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: По какому принципу надо дёргать методы из класса? Они должны иметь что-то общее в названии? Или должны быть просто вызываемыми?

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте так:

```
classes = FirstClass, SecondClass, ThirdClass
classes = sum([[i, i] for i in classes], [])
mapper = {f"check_method_{i}": getattr(class_, f"check_method_{i}") for class_, i in zip(classes, range(1, 7))}
```

либо так

```
classes = FirstClass, SecondClass, ThirdClass
classes = sum([[i, i] for i in classes], [])
methods = "check_method_1", "check_method_2", "check_method_3", "check_method_4", "check_method_5", "check_method_6"
mapper = {method: getattr(class_, method) for method in zip(classes, methods)}
```

Comment: мне надо было более точно сформулировать вопрос. Наименования методов классов не обязательно должно было заканчиваться цифрами. Но подход мне понравился. Поэтому Ваш ответ очень полезен.

Answer (score 1):

@Danis, ваше решение натолкнуло на такую мысль и я решил проблему. Получилось весьма лаконично:

```
result = {k: v for c in classes for k, v in c.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('__')}
```

Comment: `{k: v for c in classes for k, v in c.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('__') and callable(v)}` ?

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо. Хорошее замечание